# json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I want to create a CRUD rest API to manage casts using Gorm and Gin. When I add a relation between two of my models, I cannot create a cast because of that converting the string ID to a struct type.

My Models:

```
type Cast struct {
    ID            string    `sql:"type:uuid;primary_key;default:uuid_generate_v4()"`
    FullName      string    `gorm:"size:150;not null" json:"full_name"`
    NickNames     string    `gorm:"size:250;null;" json:"nick_names"`
    BornLocation  Country   `gorm:"many2many:CastBornLocation;association_foreignkey:ID;foreignkey:ID" json:"born_location"`
    Nationalities []Country `gorm:"many2many:Castnationalities;association_foreignkey:ID;foreignkey:ID" json:"cast_nationalities"`
    MiniBio       string    `gorm:"size:1000;null;" json:"mini_bio"`
}

type Country struct {
    ID        string    `sql:"type:uuid;primary_key;default:uuid_generate_v4()"`
    Title     string    `gorm:"size:100;not null" json:"title"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"updated_at"`
}
```

And here is the controller:

```
func (server *Server) CreateCast(c *gin.Context) {
    errList = map[string]string{}
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
    if err != nil {
        errList["Invalid_body"] = "Unable to get request"
        c.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "status": http.StatusUnprocessableEntity,
            "error":  errList,
        })
        return
    }

    item := models.Cast{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &item)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("---------------------------------")
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println("---------------------------------")
        errList["Unmarshal_error"] = "Cannot unmarshal body"
        c.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "status": http.StatusUnprocessableEntity,
            "error":  errList,
        })
        return
    }
    ...
```

And this is the JSON body I'm submitting to the API:

```
{
    "full_name": "Cast fullname",
    "nick_names": "nickname1, nickname2",
    "born_location": "01346a2e-ae50-45aa-8b3e-a66748a76955",
    "Nationalities": [
        "c370aa49-b39d-4797-a096-094b84903f27",
        "01346a2e-ae50-45aa-8b3e-a66748a76955"
    ],
    "mini_bio": "this is the mini bio of the cast"
}
```

And this is the full printed error:

> json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Cast.born_location of type models.Country

Comment: The error is very specific. What is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not unmarshal string into Struct type. `BornLocation` is country struct type but you are sending the only id of string type in JSON. Same for `Nationalities`. Try to send id in id node inside of the object to map with your struct.

```
{
    "full_name": "Cast fullname",
    "nick_names": "nickname1, nickname2",
    "born_location": {
        "id" :"01346a2e-ae50-45aa-8b3e-a66748a76955"
    }
    "Nationalities": [
        {
           "id" :"c370aa49-b39d-4797-a096-094b84903f27"
        },
        {
           "id" :"01346a2e-ae50-45aa-8b3e-a66748a76955"
        }
    ],
    "mini_bio": "this is the mini bio of the cast"
}
```

Or create another struct for your request body to map your current JSON.